# How to get Frequency and Interval information from AzureDataFactoryV2 TriggerResource object?

Tags: c#, triggers, azure-data-factory

So I pass triggerName to:
`client.Triggers.Get("<resourceGroupName>", "<dataFactoryName>", "<triggerName>")` function and it returns me triggerResource object. Now If I **Debug** that triggerResource object has these class attributes and functions:

```
1) triggerResource.StartTime
2) triggerResource.EndTime
3) triggerResource.Delay
4) triggerResource.Frequency
5) triggerResource.Interval
```

Now I want frequency and Interval values but these attributes are only visible when I debug not during I refer. So doing triggerResource. gives no option for frequency and Interval. This seems that are they private? Or how can I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the issue, I was actually having parent class instead of child class, So what i did is used dynamic type with explicit casting to get the right object. So that i can use its property.